# jQuery - How to include a variable in a click function

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
getAccessPointArray()
    .done(function(array) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(array);

        for ( i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++ ) {

            var identifier = obj.data[i]['identifier'];
            var url = obj.data[i]['url'];

            $( "." + identifier ).click(function() {
                alert("This is the URL: " + url );   
            });

        }

    }
);
```

My array:

```
obj = array( 'data' =>
['url' => url 1, 'identifier' => ident 1] , 
['url' => url 2, 'identifier' => ident 2]
);
```

What seems to be happening is that the url is set on the first pass, however on the second pass it does not overwrite the first url...

so my output is:

```
This is the URL: url 1
This is the URL: url 1
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `so my output is:

This is the URL: url 1` Are you sure???

Comment: Not 100% sure to be honest, only a single click event was valid at a time and when I re-tested, it appeared the loop was running outside of the click event for all iterations, then firing off the click event once done leaving the variable set to the last url in the loop so no matter which event I clicked on, the same URL was being alerted...

Comment: Ya, the last url, not the first one as you posted it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close over the i variable. You can do it with an IIFE

```
(function(i){
 var identifier = obj.data[i]['identifier'];
 var url = obj.data[i]['url'];

 $( "." + identifier ).click(function() {
  alert("This is the URL: " + url );   
 });
}(i)
```

Here is a Stack Snippet Demo

```js
var obj = {
 data : [
  { 
   url : 'world',
   identifier : 'hello'
  },
  {
   url : 'polo',
   identifier : 'marco'
  }
 ]
};
for ( var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++ ) {
 (function(i){
  var identifier = obj.data[i]['identifier'];
  var url = obj.data[i]['url'];

  $( "." + identifier ).click(function() {
    alert("This is the URL: " + url );   
  });
 })(i)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="hello">
   Hello  
  </div>
  <div class="marco">
   Marco 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh this worked a treat, thank you so much. Very new to jQuery so lots of trial and error at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried it but just in case. Try to reset the url and identifier after assigning to the click()

```
var identifier;
var url;
for ( i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++ ) {
     identifier = obj.data[i]['identifier'];
     url = obj.data[i]['url'];

    $( "." + identifier ).click(function() {
         alert("This is the URL: " + url );   
    });

    identifier = '';
    url = '';
}
```